# OrmLite / Servicestack: how to specify which table you want a column from when each table joined has the same column name?

Tags: servicestack, dto, ormlite-servicestack

I'm pretty new to these technologies and I'm having trouble with a specific issue. I have a class defined as such:

```cs
public class CameraDetail
{
    public int I_id { get; set; }
    public string C_division_id { get; set; }
    // ....some other members....
}
```

...and Servicestack is sending a List of these back from an endpoint. That's all working, but my specific endpoint is doing some table joins to get specific records, and *every* table in our database has the primary key `I_id`. So, in the current query here:

```cs
public List<CameraDetail> GetCameraDetailForStore(string storeId)
{

    List<CameraDetail> ret = null;

    // this is inside a using statement I didn't copy, just assume 'conn' exists
    conn.Open();

    ret = conn.Select<CameraDetail>(
        conn.From<cctv_camera>()
            .Join<cctv_camera, cctv_dvr>((c, d) => c.C_dvr_id == d.C_dvr_id)
            .And<cctv_dvr>(d => d.C_store_id == storeId)
            .Join<cctv_camera, cctv_vendor>((c, v) => c.C_vendor_id == v.C_vendor_id)
            .Where(c => c.C_store_id == storeId))
}
```

...I am getting back the primary key `I_id`s from the `cctv_vendor` table when I actually need them from the `cctv_camera` table.

I've tried `.PopulateWith` and `.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues`, but haven't exactly had much luck. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or if anyone has any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OrmLite docs includes examples showing how you can [select data from multiple tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#select-data-from-multiple-tables-into-a-custom-poco) where you can get the specific filed from the table you want by prepending the **table name** to the **field name** in your custom table, e.g to get the `I_id` field from the `cctv_camera` you can use:

```
public class CameraDetail
{
    public int cctv_cameraI_id { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [BelongsTo attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#belongsto-attribute), e.g:

```
public class CameraDetail
{
    [BelongTo(typeof(cctv_camera))]
    public int I_id { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you want to use a completely different name in your model you can just use a property getter, e.g:

```
public class CameraDetail
{
    public int Id => cctv_cameraI_id;
    public int cctv_cameraI_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good info! Unfortunately, this class and the `I_id` is already being used in capacity around the app, front-end and backend, and I don't think people will be happy if I changed the property. Is there any other possible way to get around this?